# Output data in real time

Tags: python, linux

I have two Python scripts for Linux.

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

print('first line')
subprocess.run('./test_1.py', shell=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

test_1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print('second line')
```

If I run `test.py` as:

```
./test.py
```

It print:

```
first line
second line
```

It's good result.

But if I use:

```
./test.py > test
```

File `test` contain strings:

```
second line
first line
```

`second line` is first. Why?

I try to play with `subprocess.stdout`, `subprocess.stderr`, `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` - it not correctly work in my case any way.

One case work for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

print('first line')
text = subprocess.run('./test_1.py', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True, encoding='utf-8')

print(text.stdout)
```

I that case `test` look ok.

BUT there is one moment. `print(text.stdout)` will be executed after `test_1.py` completes. All output data will capture in variable. And I don't see the actual, real process of running `test_1.py`. I can see all the data afterwards, if process of running `test_1.py` will be take a lot of time.

Questions:

1. `second line` is first. Why do I get different result in both cases?
2. Is it possible to get the output of subscripts in the correct format and in real time? I'm interesting in two cases of running:

```
./test.py
```

and

```
./test.py > test
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering) Also see: [catching stdout in realtime from subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606795/catching-stdout-in-realtime-from-subprocess)

Comment: You're basically running two processes each of which have their own buffer for the output. The subprocess exits first and flushes its buffer and then your actual process. Also you probably don't need to use `shell=True` for whatever you're trying to do there.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you. These links partially answer my questions. I still don’t understand why the buffering is different in both cases? Why do I get different result in both cases? How is work first case and how is work second cases? I mean if I run `./test.py` and `./test.py > test`.

Comment: When you run `./test.py` stdout points to your terminal which is an interactive environment hence the output is line-buffered, When you run `./test.py > test` stdout is pointing to a file which is not interactive so the output is block-buffered. See: [Python script differs output between terminal and redirection to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27967589/python-script-differs-output-between-terminal-and-redirection-to-a-file)

Comment: `test_1.py` runs to completion, and the files are flushed as the process closes.  You then get back to `test.py`, which still has stuff in its buffer.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat If you give answer I vote it. Thank you again.

Comment: @Pro I've pointed you to duplicates that answer each of your question, you can accept the duplicate and upvote them. :)

Comment: You can also get the same output by manually flushing immediately before the subprocess call: `sys.stdout.flush()`